# Entity Framework Model and ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2: Ρroblem with umlauts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, diacritics

I have this piece of a HTML in a View:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.HändlerID })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.HändlerID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.HändlerName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.HändlerOrt) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
```

The item is an entity which contain properties with umlauts (Händler...) as u can see.
Now, when I start the page an error occurs. The "ä" is transformed in a strange character.

Comment: Don't use umlauts? I mean - seriously, why do you use them?

Comment: Could u be more precise about the "strange error"?

Comment: the umlaut is transformed in a kind of circle ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to re-save your view in different encoding. It's a really loooooong shot, but who knows.

> in VS => File => Advanced Save Options => Unicode 650001 => OK

Comment: I used this already, but without signatures ... when I use the option with sigantures it works. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Despite that I'm quite surprised I guessed it correctly. :D